# How to roll back all commits from certain branch in GIT?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I created new branch from master on 08/01 "12345-Fix"

- 08/01 Commit 1 in local
- 08/02 Commit 2 in local
- 08/03 Commit 3 in local

I created new branch from/ master on 08/04 "56789-Fix"

- 08/04 Commit 4 in local
- 08/05 Commit 5 in local

On 08/05 I pushed the "56789-Fix" branch code to remote master branch so this pushed both commit 4 and commit 5 in master branch.

Started working back on "12345-Fix" on 08/06

- 08/06 Commit 6 in local
- 08/07 Commit 7 in local

On 08/07 I pushed the "12345-Fix" branch code to remote master so this pushed all 5 commits (1,2,3,6,7) in master branch.

Now when I looked up in Github, the commit listing is showing as

- Commit 7 08/07
- Commit 6 08/06
- Commit 5 08/05
- Commit 4 08/04
- Commit 3 08/03
- Commit 2 08/02
- Commit 1 08/01

**My Question is if I want to rollback only "12345-Fix" branch code from master branch, how I can do that?** I know I can roll back to certain commit "Commit 1", but than it will rollback Commit 4 and Commit 5 for "56789-Fix", which I don't want to roll back.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please tell me which commits do you need?

Comment: I need to keep commit 4 and 5. or let's take it in different way I need to remove Commit (1,2,3,6,7) and keep all the other commits.

Answer (score 1):

Since the commits have been pushed, you will need to create one or more new commits that undo the effects of commits 1,2,3,6, and 7. The command for this is `git revert`.

I would want to do something like

`git revert --no-commit 1 2 3 6 7`

then check that the changes made by `git revert` are the ones you intended, and then commit these undos with a normal `git commit`.

You will need to identify each of the commits properly in the command and **cannot** use the numbers as shown.  I suggest using the first few characters of each of the commit ID's in place of each of the small integers I show above, or you can use revision ranges for example if you feel confident.

Answer (score 0):

At first rest to HEAD - 2

Remove 6, 7

1. `git reset HEAD~2`
2. `git checkout .`

Record 4, 5 with git stash

1. `git reset HEAD~1`
2. `git stash`
3. `git reset HEAD~1`
4. `git stash`

Reset to the commit before 1 with git reset HEAD~3(Remove 1, 2, 3
)

1. `git reset HEAD~3`
2. `git checkout .`

Pop recorded commit(4, 5) with git stash pop

1. `git stash pop`
2. `git commit -am "commit 4"`
3. `git stash pop`
4. `git commit -am "commit 5"`

`git push origin master -f`